# Sql query from related tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

shopping:

```
id  buyer   fruit
1   1 [->]  2 [->]
2   2 [->]  2 [->]
```

fruits:

```
id  fruit
1   apple
2   banana
```

buyers:

```
id  buyer
1   ido
2   omri
```

I want to extract from the table of 'shopping' and put the values of the other tables ​​in the row.
For example:
Row number one in 'shopping' should look like this:

```
id  buyer   fruit
1   ido     banana
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to join the related tables on their respective IDs:

```
SELECT s.id, b.buyer, f.fruit 
FROM shopping s
JOIN fruits f ON s.fruit = f.id
JOIN buyers b ON s.buyer = b.id
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!!
Just a slight correction, the first line should be
SELECT s.id, b.buyer, f.fruit

Comment: Oops, you are right, it is edited to show the correct fields.